# Java FTP Uploaded Images Corrupted

Tags: java, ftp, java-io, fileinputstream, apache-commons-net

I'm trying to upload some files to a Local FTP server. The observable list has all the files, and are uploaded by looping the array
I'm using the `commons-net-3.6.jar` Library.

The Directory and everything get's created but the images uploaded are corrupted. 
Huge change in color (looks like an old static TV image with colors) 
What am i doing wrong?

**NOTE!** 
 Something I noticed was that the sizes of file's are the same in KB but differs slightly by bytes.

```
    ObservableList<File> uploadFiles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    InputStream fis = null;

    FTPConnection con = new FTPConnection();
    con.readData();  //gets username and password

    uploadFiles  = Something.getFiles(); //Gets Files

    try {
        client.connect(con.getServerIp());
        client.login(con.getUsername(), con.getPassword());

        String pathname = getPathname();

        client.makeDirectory(pathname);


        for (int i = 0; i < uploadFiles.size(); i++) {


            fis = new FileInputStream(uploadFiles.get(i)); 
            String filename = uploadFiles.get(i).getName();

            String uploadpath = pathname+"/"+filename;
            System.out.println("Uploading File : " + uploadpath);
            client.storeFile(uploadpath, fis);



        }



        client.logout();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();




    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

[image: output image sample]

Comment: As per Javadocs *The default settings for FTPClient are for it to use FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE* - you may want to change this to binary

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thanks that did the Trick.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the file type to Binary did the Trick!

```
client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```